# Changes to $location service are not getting reflected into the browser address bar

Tags: angularjs, location

I have a function as below which is used to route to particular pages. The issue here is `$location.url(url).search(search);` is getting executed and I can see the changes reflected in debugger, but the changes are not getting reflected into the browser address bar.

```
var routeToPage = function (page, search) {
    if (angular.isDefined(page) && null !== page) {
        var url = page;
        url = url.substring(url.length-1) === '/'? url.substring(0, url.length-1): url;
        $timeout(function () {
            if (search) {
                $location.url(url).search(search);

            } else {
                $location.url(url);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I tried `$window.location.assign(url);` and its working fine but I need search parameters also. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$scope.apply` after `$location.url(url).search(search);`

Comment: Added `$scope.$apply()` and finally my issue is resolved.Thank you.